# CSS: How can I center my title and navigation at the top of the page?

Tags: html, css

My html:

```
<div id="headerDiv">
    <div id="titleDiv">
        <p id= "titleText">Title</p>
    </div>
    <ul id="navUL">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Browse</li>
        <li>Statistics</li>
        <li>Calculator</li>
        <li>Blaster</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
#headerDiv{
position: fixed;
height:12%;
width:200%;
background-color:black;
text-allign: center;
}

#titleDiv{
width: auto;
margin: auto;
}

#navUL{
list-style-type:none;
margin: auto 0;
padding:0;
border-top:1 solid;
border-right:1 solid;
border-left:1 solid;
width:100%;
}

#navUL li{
padding: .2em 1em;
color: #fff;
background-color: #036;
display:inline-block;
text-allign:center;
}
```

I want my header to be fixed at the top of the page with the title and navigation to be centered within the header, but can't for the life of me get these elements centered without setting the margins manually. I've tried applying text-align:center on the parent div and children, margin:auto, margin:auto 0, and nothing.

Could someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Can you put it in a JSFiddle please?

Comment: Please review my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things...

1) You currently have an extra 'l' in your CSS property ie `text-allign: center;`

2) Width of `#headerDiv`should not be more than 100%

3) Title needs colour adding to it etc etc

```
#titleText{
    color:white
}
```

To sum it up... replace your CSS with this...

```
#headerDiv{
    position: fixed;
    background-color:black;
    text-align: center;
    overflow:auto
}

#titleDiv{
    width: auto;
    margin: auto;
}

#navUL{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin: auto 0;
    padding:0;
    border-top:1 solid;
    border-right:1 solid;
    border-left:1 solid;
    width:100%;
}

#navUL li{
    padding: .2em 1em;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #036;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
}

#titleText{
    color:white
}
```

Comment: Don't know why someone downvoted you but this was the answer I was looking for. The extra "l" in text-align" was my issue. My vote for you can't show because I am under the 15 point threshold. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, I don't either, some people aye!

Answer (score -1):

Is the title next to the navbar links or above them? Also you need to set the title to have a white color in order to see it... Why did you use 200% for header width? and what is the point of borders in navUL? Have a look at my code

```css
#headerDiv {
    position: fixed;
    width:100%;
    background-color:black;
    text-align: center;
}

#titleDiv {
    width: auto;
    color:#FFF;
}

#navUL {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
}

#navUL li {
    padding: .2em 1em;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #036;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="headerDiv">
    <div id="titleDiv">
        <p id= "titleText">Title</p>
    </div>
    <ul id="navUL">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Browse</li>
        <li>Statistics</li>
        <li>Calculator</li>
        <li>Blaster</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Run @Aziz code snippet... Is this not what you want?